# REACT - Check authentication before render APP

Tags: reactjs

Im really stuck here and im not sure why, im kind of new to React so every help i can get would be consider great :D!

I have stored a JWT token inside localstorage when USER is signed in, when we refresh the page i have this function to check if the user is authenticated so we can set the user again.

```
async checkLoginStatus() {
    console.log('checking');
    const token = localStorage.getItem('sid');
    if (token) {
      let user = await VerifyUser(token);
      if (user) {
        this.setState({
          isLoggedin: true,
          user: user
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          isLoggedin: false,
          user: {}
        });
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoggedin: false,
        user: {}
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkLoginStatus();
  }
```

Here is my routes atm, dont mind the diff of the codes, testing some stuff

```
<Router>
            <Header handleLogin={this.handleLogin} isLoggedin={this.state.isLoggedin} handleLogout={this.handleLogout} />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
              <Route exact path="/" component={ () => <Home user={this.state.user}/> } />
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/user" isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedin} component={User} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Here is my PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Comp, isLoggedIn, path, ...rest }) => {
    return (
      <Route path={path} {...rest} render={props => {
          return isLoggedIn ? (<Comp {...props} />) : (<Redirect to="/" />);
        }}
      />
    );
  };

export default PrivateRoute;
```

When the user is logged in they can access the Protected page, but when they are logged out they cannot. So that works fine. And when i refresh page anywhere on the site, it checks if we have a token and it login the user, this is not the problem aswell.

The problem is when i am standing on /user <- the protected page, and i refresh page, the user is not logged in, i guess because the function where we check the user to be logged in has not been done yet when we try to render that route. Ive tried changing componentDidMount to componentWillMount with no results.

Any suggestions?

Comment: PLease provide the code directly here to avoid clicking and going to links and see images

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI how? , copy paste?

Comment: Yes yes please.

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI Done, just got my account, 1st question, found out now how to do it :)

Comment: the checkLoginStatus is a function in app.js where i render the whole page

Comment: you need to do the isLoggedIn check inside your protected route and the function should be called inside your protected route

Here you'll find an example https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Comment: @SifatHaque i have been following that example and tested it out, something gets wrong here aswell. Becouse he does not explain how to  get it to work with a real function that is checking the server with the token. He is using a FakeAuth code. While i want to use a function to send request to server, i can add theese codes to the question so you can take a look at it!

Comment: @SifatHaque now ive updated the code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that initial value of `isLoggedIn` is falsey, which triggers the redirect (before the state is updated asynchronously):

```
isLoggedIn ? (<Comp {...props} />) : (<Redirect to="/" />)
```

What you need is 3 states for 'loading', 'login succes' and 'login fail'.

Example with 2 boolean variables:

```
state = {
  isLoading: true,
  isLoggedIn: false,
  user: {}
}
...
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      isLoggedIn: false
    })
...
    isLoggedIn ? (<Comp {...props} />) : (isLoading ? 'Loading...' : <Redirect to="/" />)
```

(the same can be achieved with initial state `isLoggedIn: null` and condition `isLoggedIn === null` if you prefer fewer variables)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, just one question. When do i set loading true from false and so on?

Comment: If you need to load it only once, then never. If you can reset `isLoggedIn` from true to false (and `user` to empty object) after manual click on Logout, then the right place to reset `isLoading` would be after manual click on Login after the logout.

Comment: This fixed everything. Thank you so much for this i love you!